# Run Python and Php under same server

Tags: nginx, php, python

I am trying to run python on main domain and a wordpress blog in sub-directory. Is it possible to do so?

Currently the they are running good in sub-domains
i.e http://main-domain.com and blog.main-domain.com

but i read that from SEOs point of view it is better to have it like
http://main-domain.com/blog

I am using nginx as the server. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You do realize that `python` isn't the name of a language, not a server or web framework, right? Most of your question makes no sense. Is it a CGI server? FCGI? WSGI? What actual frameworks are you using? That having been said, I've figured out what you probably meant, and yes, it is possible.

Comment: I am sorry that i didn't make it clear. I am running a website built with django  using gunicorn with fcgi.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use the nginx [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) directive, as is done in this [example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/uwsgi/#configuring-nginx) of reverse-proxying a flask application.

In fact, even for the same location (as in that example), you can use [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) to check a bunch of locations in order, and then serve up a 50x message. It's pretty nice.

I can't give you more specific details, because you have told me very, very little about your actual setup.